# purpose of catch any in JVM

Tags: exception, jvm, .class-file

In Java bytecode, there is an option to specify the constant pool index 0 as the exception handler type, allowing you to catch all exceptions. However, as I understand it, this is exactly identical to catching Throwable. So what is the purpose of this feature? Did the designers of Java one day envision adding types of exceptions that don't inherit from Throwable? It doesn't look like it, but I can't think of another explanation apart from laziness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [JVM specification (§4.7.3)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.3) states:

> If the value of the `catch_type` item is zero, this exception handler is called for all exceptions. This is used to implement `finally` (§3.13).

Although the use of catch_type zero is not specifically discussed in §3.13, the hint that it is used when compiling `finally` clauses in Java gives a clue. It may be that the JVM designers wanted a simple way to refer to *all* exception types without having to specifically refer to the `Throwable` class. The use of catch_type zero would be easier for the JVM to identify rather than having to index into the constant pool and resolve the `java/lang/Throwable` class name there.

In practical terms, as you say a catch_type zero or an index into the constant pool referring to `java/lang/Throwable` should work identically.

Comment: So it basically is laziness. I guess that makes sense. By the way, it isn't just used for Finally. It's also used for exception handling in synchronized blocks.